# Black line in Spyder

Tags: spyder

[image]
Why does line 14 appear in a bold style in my Spyder software?

How can I make it so its not bold?

Answer (score 25):

It is to help in styling, to help you keep within 80 characters per line of code. You can cancel it by going to preference>editor>uncheck "show vertical line after xx characters".

Answer (score 8):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) In Spyder **4.2.0** the option to show/hide that line is present in

`Tools > Preferences > Completion and linting > Code style`.

*Note*: `Code style` will be renamed to `Code style and formatting` in Spyder **4.2.1**, to be released on December 18th 2020.

Answer (score 3):

It is bold because that is the line number you have the cursor on.  If you move the cursor to another line, it will change what line number is bold-styled.